# Gazebo_ros spawn_model reference_frame not working

Tags: ros, spawn-model, gazebo-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am launching the following world with the `empty_world.launch` file:

```
<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name"   value="$(find my_pkg)/world.world" />
</include>
```

Where `world.world` is:

```
<sdf version="1.5">
  <world name="default">
    <include>
      <uri>model://sun</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
      <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
    </include>
    

    <!-- Extra objects -->
    <model name='unit_cylinder_1'>
        <pose>0 0 2 3.141592 0 1.57</pose>
    ...
```

I am also launching the following:

```
<node ns="alpha" name="spawn_robot" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" output="screen"
      args="-param robot_description
            -urdf -model alpha
            -robot_namespace alpha
            -reference_frame unit_cylinder_1
            -x 2
            -y 4
            -z 0"/>
```

But I keep getting this error: `Spawn status: SpawnModel: reference reference_frame not found, did you forget to scope the link by model name?` Parameter `robot_description` is in the `alpha` namespace and it is a valid URDF (it works if I remove the `-reference_frame`).

Basically, my question is: is there a bug on the `-reference_frame` argument or is there something else I am missing? Maybe is related with namespaces or something.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229879/gazebo_ros-spawn_model-reference_frame-not-working/) by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1305 on 2016-03-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(cross-answered in http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8900/spawn-a-box-in-another-frame-than-world/#14360)

From experimentation, the `-reference_frame` option in spawn_model must be relative to a link in a model in the world. So in your case, the following modifications should work:

world.world:

```
...
<!-- Extra objects -->
<model name='unit_cylinder_1'>
    <pose>0 0 2 3.141592 0 1.57</pose>
    <link name='my_link'>
        ....
   </link>
...
```

And in your node args `-reference_frame unit_cylinder_1::my_link`

---

Originally posted by [mrjogo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1576/mrjogo/) with karma: 164 on 2016-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1